# AWS MediaConvert Docs are obnoxious and unclear

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-media-convert

I have been messing with AWS MediaConvert for boto3 for the python library and I find the docs incredibly confusing.

There are so many settings.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mediaconvert.html

and amazon does a absoultely terrible job of labeling what is necessary to do a basic job.

what would be the correct json for a simple job.

taking a video with audio file and turning it into a CMAF file

and taking a audio only file and turning it into A CMAF file.

I am trying to establish the baseline use of this technology. And there is so much extra that I don't know what I absolutely need and what is extra settings for specific use cases.

Comment: im going through the ui and going to copy the JSON that comes from the UI and work with that.

Comment: The APIs that are used by the web console are different than the public APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve for this is to use the MediaConvert UI in AWS then use the copy json button save it and then use the json created.

Never mind trying to create it yourself. Unless you like pain.